# UITableView in UIViewController - Connecting cells to UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a *UITableView* in a *UIViewController*. I have other UIViewControllers created in Storyboard that I want to connect to my cells.

How can I connect *UIViewControllers* created in Storyboard to my cells?

---

**MyViewController.h**

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,    UITableViewDataSource> {
    IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *myTableView;
```

---

**MyViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"CELL1", @"CELL2 & CELL3", nil];
    self.listData = array;
    [array release];

    [myTableView setDataSource:self];
    [myTableView setDelegate:self];

    [[self view] addSubview:myTableView];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [listData count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UpdatesTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UpdatesTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (UIView *view in views) {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                cell = (UpdatesTableViewCell*)view;
            }
        }
    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either create segues from this controller to the other ones and then choose which segue to perform when someone taps a cell or you can use a reference to the storyboard to call `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` and make that controller active on a tap.

Comment: thanks, I would like to use a reference to the storyboard to call instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier but I don't know where to call it and how? (in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?)

Comment: That seems like the right place.  If your current view controller came from the same storyboard, then `self.storyboard` should give you a reference you can use to make the call.